# Adequacy test on a septic system to sell house

Tags: septic

Does any one out there know how to figure the adequacy test on a 1000 gal septic system?  It's required here to sell your house. It's an engineer question but I don't know any.

I know you add water, say 500 gallons, to your leach field and see how fast it goes down. I have an 8ft deep trench with 24" of standing water to start, I added 500 gallons of water to the leach field which raised the water level to 44". The water went down one inch per hour for the first 12 hours. Now 24 hours later it is still at 36" and has stopped leaching.

Question: does it pass and what is the formula the engineers use?

It's had the 24" the past 10 years and I assume it will get back there again. The system is 20 years old and I pump it every 5 years. Still a lot of trench for me to fill but I may want to sell it.

Comment: It would seem like a test like this should need to be performed by a (disinterested) 3rd party, not the seller.   Do home inspection companies in your area have the expertise?  Ask your real estate agent who must test and certify the results.

Comment: Sir, I just want to know if it passes.  It cost $800 to have it done by an engineer.  If I sell it  that's what I will need to do.  But why do that if I know it will not pass.  No refunds.

Comment: Choose your company, and then ask them how you can pre-test.  Where are you on the planet? I googled this the other night and only seemed to find Alaska references.